# Utilisation de « on » ou de la voix passive

Tags: grammaire, passif

Je voudrais bien savoir s'il y a une différence entre ces deux phrases :

> - On me l'a rapporté de Chine.
> - Il m'a été rapporté de Chine.

Aussi, dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces phrases ?

Quelle est celle qui est la plus utilisée par les francophones ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*On* est très courant, surtout en français parlé.

Contrairement à l'anglais, la forme passive est parfois même rarement utilisée car il est plus facile/rapide de dire « on ne sait pas ».

Il faut également noter que les deux cas ne sont pas toujours comparables. *On* ne sert pas qu'à remplacer des formes passives, *on* est le pronom indéfini et il peut être sympathique de l'utiliser en tant que tel. E.g. : « On doit le faire » précise que cela doit être fait sans préciser qui doit le faire ainsi cette figure de style peut être utilisée pour insister sur le pronom indéfini et non plus seulement comme une facilité de langage.

> On apprend tous les jours.

Certains trouvent cependant l'utilisation de *on* incorrecte (car pas assez relevée) et préfèrent ainsi l'éviter si possible.

**Nota Bene :** *On*, même s'il réfère souvent à plusieurs personnes (comme lorsqu'il est utilisé pour remplacer *nous*), ne doit pas être conjugué au pluriel mais comme s'il s'agissait de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier. **Exemple :** *On était bien* et non **On étaient bien*.

Comment: S'il vous plaît, quelle est la différence entre "on doit le faire" et "il est nécessaire de le faire" ou encore "il faut le faire" ?  Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Il n'y en a pas beaucoup. Toutes veulent dire la même chose. La dernière est parfois utilisé comme expression "ca il faut le faire !" quand on est choqué. _On_ est souvent moins formel et plus courant dans le francais parlé qu'écrit.