# Mode d'emploi de la voix passive

Tags: grammaire, sens, formulation-idiomatique, voix-passive

Bonjour,

La première façon de parler qui me vient à l'esprit est :

> On m'a volé mon téléphone !

Par contre, je pense que je pourrais également dire :

> Mon téléphone a été volé !

et bien aussi

> Quelqu'un a volé mon téléphone !

Je voudrais donc demander quelle est la différence entre ces trois phrases, mais surtout les deux premières, vu que je pense que la troisième met l'emphase sur la personne qui a volé le téléphone plutôt que le téléphone qui a été volé lui-même (et aussi, à proprement parler, il ne s'agit pas là de la voix passive).

Comment: Le deuxième exemple est la seule phrase qui emploie la voix passive donc . . . ?  Puis moi je dirais *quelq'un a piqué mon portable !* Au feu les pompiers ! : ) mais ça dépend du contexte.

Comment: En français on emploie beaucoup moins la voix passive qu'en anglais. Le français emploie *on* là où l'anglais emploie la voix passive, quand j'entends « Mon téléphone a été volé » je me dis : « tiens un anglophone ! ».  La distinction que tu donnes dans ton dernier paragraphe ne se fait guère en français, elle est enseignée à ceux qui apprennent l'anglais en tant que langue étrangère ([e.g.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/active-vs-passive-voice-difference).

Comment: Et il y a déjà de [très nombreuses questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=voix+passive) sur le sujet sur FL [e.g.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/utilisation-de-on-ou-de-la-voix-passive) et il y en a d'autres.

Comment: *Je me suis fait voler mon téléphone !*

Comment: @jlliagre _On m'a chouré mon téléphone!_

Comment: @Frank *Un larron a dérobé mon Nokia !*

Comment: @jlliagre Vraiment? On utilise encore _larron_? Pas plutôt, _kaïra_? (je le mets en "Grec" hahaha)

Comment: @Frank L'occasion fait le larron !

Comment: @jiliagre *Je m'suis fait tchar mon tel !*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Utilisation de « on » ou de la voix passive](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/utilisation-de-on-ou-de-la-voix-passive)

Answer (score 0):

*On **m'a** volé mon téléphone !* C'est la voix active.

*Mon téléphone **m'a** été volé !* C'est la voix passive (on n'écrit pas "par on").

*Quelqu'un **m'a** volé mon téléphone !* C'est la voix active.

*Mon téléphone **m'a** été volé **par quelqu'un***. C'est la voix passive.

La différence entre les deux, c'est qu'on ne dit pas "par on", mais on peut dire "par quelqu'un". Dans la première phrase, vous utilisez **"on"** et la deuxième phrase vous utilisez **"quelqu'un"** ce qui n'est pas la même chose. Il ne faut pas croire que "Mon téléphone m'a été volé" peut être aussi la voix passive de "quelqu'un m'a volé mon téléphone".

Comment: Je ne suis pas la logique de la dernière phrase, c'est le contraire de ta réponse ?